# VBA code to convert/import specific datafile data to a XbyY excel form

Tags: vba, excel

Datafile contains 16 lines with 16 char per line.
Want to get this data into a 16x16 excel table.

Sample code below (from one of the posts here), but no "|" char used so don't know what needs changing to do the task.

[VBA code snippet from previous Q asked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKJAn.png)

Example of datafile contents below.
The . (period) means a blank to appear in the cell column.

```
.2A.....5C.9..6G

6..G.5471A82.D..

.8...B2...E7...A

....6AE..4GF3.87

1E7.C8..G.46FBA9

.D.....4.E.3.CG.

.F.C.2A571B.683E

A.5..9...2.C7.D.

..3.A..9.8.4.EBD

..E6.G1D.....3..

C.....7..D1..A4.

DA.....63.7EC...

3...F.9....85G..

........EB..DF98

EB.A5..2...1....

F.9.B.8..75GA.2.
```

Thanks for any help ...

Comment: Please copy and paste your code into the question, and describe exactly what the problem is.

Comment: For starters, an explicit question has a question mark in it. Please make your question explicit and specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Read_and_Save_XbyY()
    Dim path As String
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim excelName As String
    Dim parts() As String
    Dim wbData As Workbook
    Dim wsData As Worksheet

    path = "D:\temp\X_by_Y\"
    fileName = "MyData.txt"

    ' Prepare filenames
    parts = Split(fileName, ".")
    excelName = parts(LBound(parts)) + ".xlsx"

    ' Open inputfile
    Workbooks.OpenText (path + fileName)
    Set wbData = Workbooks(fileName)
    Set wsData = wbData.Worksheets(1)

    ' Split into 16 columns
        wsData.[A1:A16].TextToColumns _
            Destination:=[A1], _
            DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
            FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 2), Array(1, 2), Array(2, 2), Array(3, 2), Array(4, 2), _
                          Array(5, 2), Array(6, 2), Array(7, 2), Array(8, 2), Array(9, 2), _
                          Array(10, 2), Array(11, 2), Array(12, 2), Array(13, 2), _
                          Array(14, 2), Array(15, 2))

    ' Save xlsx file
    wbData.SaveAs fileName:=path + excelName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook

    ' Close data workbook
    wbData.Close

End Sub
```